Mid-sentence phrase where you need 1 of 2 things but could also have both as well
I have been losing sleep over this, I have used this string of words before but can not think of it  the best way I can describe it is in the title I believe it uses a combination of “if, and, or” and is 3-4 words long and would go mid-sentence.

You might be looking for the phrase if not both. Here's an example sentence from NYT:

Joseph Parilla, a fellow at the Brookings Institution’s Metropolitan Policy Program, warned that perceptions of either uncertainty or hostility — if not both — could be corrosive to the domestic travel industry.

